# how to delay background color transition using css

Tags: html, css

Hey I am new to development so was trying to change background color when we change menu item, I have done that, but want to have some delay in changing of background color.I tried transition property but got no result.Is transition property not applicable to `<body>`?As I tried to provide 'id' to `<body>` and apply rule like this

```
<body id="color">
```

CSS

```
#color {
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    transition: background-color 2s ;
}
```

I am doing something wrong? What is the way to apply `<div>` to full page and apply the same rule?

Answer (score 3):

First, when using transitions, you need to add the `-webkit` for Safari - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition.asp

If you want a transition effect that takes x amount of time, you can exclude the below `transition-delay`. But if you want your transition to be delayed by, say 2 seconds, then you can add the `transition-delay` and set it you the amount of seconds you want to delay the transition for.

```
#color {
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 2s ease-in; /* Safari */
          transition: background-color 2s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 2s; /* Safari */
          transition-delay: 2s;
```

Here is a list of some timing-functions you can use for transitions - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-timing-function.asp

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gt6zn/) to show you how the `border-color` transition takes `.5` seconds to start on hover.

Comment: Perhaps you could create a [Fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/) of what you have so far.

Comment: sorry but I tried using fiddle, not getting how to upload all my pages to it. Anyway thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

This will work only once while CSS being loaded if this id overwrites preceding or default rules. You might not even noticed it.

Once CSS is loaded, it remains in your browsers and nothing will happen anymore.

You may give a try to link your CSS file with a time stamp to force refreshing CSS each time you reload a page. kind of like `/myCssFile.css&id=010012014`

Actually, the good practise would be to add a class on `onload` event and set your `transition` or `animation` from there.

CSS is not really meant to do this.

---

*Here is a test i made a while ago : http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/rmhAp You may see an animation the very first time your browser will load it.*

Comment: Thanks for reply, but as I am new cannot really get what you saying. Do you mean I must apply this via jQuery?Understood little bit what you saying but not got solution

Comment: @user3601687 yes jQuery or plain javascript

Answer (score -3):

[Mabye This Will Help](http://www.dynamicsights.com/csscolorcycle.html)

This continually changes the background color.

Comment: Try adding some code instead of giving direct links, or spare some of your precious time to explain what you have actually understood from the link and explain it. The link you provided has removed.